# Getting HTTPS to work when using basicHttpBinding

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, binding

I am using WCF4 and having troubles getting a service to work over https

I have create a wcf service and deployed to server and it is working ok over http. As soon as I change the web.config endpoint address to be https I get an error

> Service 'NS.WebWCF.BusinessV1' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.

My web.config looks like

```
 <services>
  <service name="NS.WebWCF.Business_v1">
    <endpoint address="https://mydomain.com/business/v1/BusinessV1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="NS.WebWCF.IBusinessV1" listenUri="/" isSystemEndpoint="true">
     </endpoint>
  </service>
```

I have set my IIS to require SSL. However I get the above error.

What do I need to do to get https to work?

Answer (score 12):

Try this one:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings >

    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webBinding">
        <security mode="Transport">
        </security>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>

  </bindings>

  <services>
    <service ...>
      <endpoint bindingConfiguration="webBinding" .../>
    </service>
  </services>

</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I had a similar issue, different error message and the solution was to set the security mode to Transport since I was trying to use Https.

Comment: I found this helpful: http://blog.adnanmasood.com/2008/07/16/https-with-basichttpbinding-note-to-self/ - although in my case just changing `mode="Transport"` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup IIS Host Header Bindings for SSL. Older versions of IIS require this to be set from the command line interface, later versions provide this tool via the GUI.

- For IIS6, check [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/596b9108-b1a7-494d-885d-f8941b07554c.mspx?mfr=true).
- For IIS7, check [here](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/ssl-host-headers-iis-7.htm).
- For IIS7.5, you should simply be able to edit the value in the "Bindings" section of the UI.

Either way, you can verify that the host headers took, because the HTML generated by the .SVC file in a browser will change.

When accessed via HTTPS:// before the bindings are correct it probably reads something like this:

> To test this service, you will need to
>   create a client and use it to call the
>   service. You can do this using the
>   svcutil.exe tool from the command line
>   with the following syntax:
>
> `svcutil.exe https://AppServerWitHIIS/VirtualDirectory/Your.svc?WSDL`

After the bindings are setup correctly in IIS, it will read:

> To test this service, you will need to
>   create a client and use it to call the
>   service. You can do this using the
>   svcutil.exe tool from the command line
>   with the following syntax:
>
> `svcutil.exe https://www.yoursslcertsite.com/your.svc?WSDL`

Comment: Hi Nate, Yes I have setup the SSL correctly as I am able to visit a test html page over https ok.
I dont have vs setup on the prod server so not sure how I can run the svcutil tool

Comment: Are you positive you have setup SSL Host Header Bindings? Even with incorrect ssl headers the site is visible when you visit in a browser, but when the service tries to send data, it ends up pointing to the wrong endpoint.

Comment: You may have to modify the existing SSL binding rather than add it. Although it's dangerous, the easiest way to do this is to modify ApplicationHost.config: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/124/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig/

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar scenario where I removed the HTTP binding and left only the HTTPS binding within IIS. The site immmediately stopped working with the error above.
To resolve, add the following within system.servicemodel in the web.config

```
<protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
```